# Display Last 200 mysql entries no dupes

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I'm just wondering how I could display my last 200 mysql entries in php without showing duplicate entries.

Comment: much better if you show us some sample tables, columns and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200`

See this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) on how to implement it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [What’s the most efficient way to select the last n rows in a table without changing the table’s structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118144/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-select-the-last-n-rows-in-a-table-without-changi) and combine wiht DISTINCT