# Using database image BLOB in "src" field

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

i have this prob. when i try to retrieve a BLOB image from database it returns a broken image any help ??
this is the code after connecting and fetching an array:

```
 <img src='",$row['pic'],"' width='331px' height='200px' />
```

Comment: `src` should point to a URI that outputs the image, it shouldn't be the image data itself. Or, you could try a data URI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214602/how-to-display-an-blob-image-stored-in-mysql-database?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database - so many related questoins, but I can't find a *duplicate* because this question is too vague about the problem and misses basic comprehension points.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `img` tags work.  You essentially have two choices:

- Create a PHP file which outputs *only* the image (probably based on a query string parameter to get the image from the database) with the correct `Content-Type` and use the URL of that file as the `src` attribute.
- Use a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to directly display the data in the `img` tag.

The latter would look something like this:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```

Where everything after the comma in the `src` value is the image data base64-encoded.