# Image from blob object not displayed in a page

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

This is my HTML code for displaying image stored as blob object which is stored in a database.

```
<tr><td>photo</td><td><img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $employee['id']; ?>" /></td></tr>
```

This is the image.php file:

```
<?php

include db.php;

$employee_id = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

try
{ 
  $sql = "SELECT photo
          FROM employee where id = $employee_id limit 1";
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $s->execute();
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{ 
  $error = 'Employee not found' . $e->getMessage();
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
} 

$employee = $s->fetch();

$image = $employee['photo'];

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;

?>
```

When I look at the HTML code in `Firebug`, I can see

```
<img src="image.php?id=9">
```

But no image is displayed in the table row. Do you know how to find out what is wrong?

When I open the page `...image.php?id=9` in Firefox
It shows a message

> The image ...image.php?id=9 cannot be
>   displayed because it contains errors.

It is strange that every image I have contains an error. I inserted only images with
size smaller than the blob object.

Comment: can you post the code which you used to insert image to blog **i use to upload image to server folder** so that database is safe and fast

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214602/how-to-display-an-blob-image-stored-in-mysql-database?rq=1

Comment: @sanojlawrence The data is inserted. I can see it in `MySQL` DB.

Comment: check this `"SELECT photo
          FROM employee where id = $employee_id limit 1";` and in image tag `<img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $employee['id']; ?>" />` change `$employee` to `$employee_id`

Answer (score 0):

do you get an error?

try to use "exit;" after the echo and remove the closing php tag.
it's optional and you don't really need it (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
exit;
```

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: @xralf image tag is located in which page

Comment: It's in ``employee.html.php`

Comment: I have found what was wrong, when I inserted the image into the database `$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));`. I removed the addslashes() function, which was recommended for security reasons. So, I hape it is still secure.