# Creating, Displaying Images From PHP

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers, blob

#### Question:

How do I get my blob image to actually work, is there a size limit to what this can handle?  I have my sql db set to longblob incase that was the problem, but everything still doesn't parse correctly.  I tried dumping the variable and I get a large blob of text, so I'm not sure whats wrong.

#### Code

```
 $image = getImgFromDB();
 header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
 echo $image;
```

[code http://s10.postimg.org/wn8m7k1s8/Screen_Shot_2015_05_08_at_10_51_46_PM.jpg](http://s10.postimg.org/wn8m7k1s8/Screen_Shot_2015_05_08_at_10_51_46_PM.jpg)

#### Research:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
- [I need my PHP page to show my BLOB image from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database)
- [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/hp-display-image-blob-from-mysql)
- [How to display an BLOB image stored in MySql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214602/how-to-display-an-blob-image-stored-in-mysql-database)
- http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40849-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php-part-ii-display-your-images/

#### Update on Insertion into the DB

The file from the row, which is checked by PHP and JS to make sure that it is the type of image and that it is within a certain size.

```
 $theImageData     = file_get_contents($filedata['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: After 2 hours, I got saving and retrieving to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 3

Header is text/plain

This is tested and should pin point the problem.

There is not much that can go wrong, so I do not understand why there is a problem.

This checks to see if the image was read in.  The length should be the same as the size of the image.  And the base 64 will show the rest.

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$filename = "pitbull3p.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$image = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$len = strlen($image);
$base64 = base64_encode($image);
echo "Length=$len\n\n" . $base64;
```

**Result**

This is my actual  result

```
Length=1864

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
```

end of update 3

### Update 2

The breaking the string into bytes works. (NOT Recommended)  But a string Hex representation does not work. A hex string  representation works in an SQL query (without the quotes, not with), but does not work with an echo.

You may be able to pack the string in to a binary string.  It is frustrating.

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpg');
$image = "\xff"."\xd8"."\xff"."\xe0"."\x00"."\x10"."\x4a"."\x46"."\x49"."\x46"."\x00"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x00"."\x48"."\x00"."\x48"."\x00"."\x00"."\xff"."\xdb"."\x00"."\x43"."\x00"."\x0a"."\x07"."\x07"."\x08"."\x07"."\x06"."\x0a"."\x08"."\x08"."\x08"."\x0b"."\x0a"."\x0a"."\x0b"."\x0e"."\x18"."\x10"."\x0e"."\x0d"."\x0d"."\x0e"."\x1d"."\x15"."\x16"."\x11"."\x18"."\x23"."\x1f"."\x25"."\x24"."\x22"."\x1f"."\x22"."\x21"."\x26"."\x2b"."\x37"."\x2f"."\x26"."\x29"."\x34"."\x29"."\x21"."\x22"."\x30"."\x41"."\x31"."\x34"."\x39"."\x3b"."\x3e"."\x3e"."\x3e"."\x25"."\x2e"."\x44"."\x49"."\x43"."\x3c"."\x48"."\x37"."\x3d"."\x3e"."\x3b"."\xff"."\xdb"."\x00"."\x43"."\x01"."\x0a"."\x0b"."\x0b"."\x0e"."\x0d"."\x0e"."\x1c"."\x10"."\x10"."\x1c"."\x3b"."\x28"."\x22"."\x28"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\x3b"."\xff"."\xc0"."\x00"."\x11"."\x08"."\x00"."\x64"."\x00"."\x64"."\x03"."\x01"."\x22"."\x00"."\x02"."\x11"."\x01"."\x03"."\x11"."\x01"."\xff"."\xc4"."\x00"."\x1b"."\x00"."\x00"."\x03"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x04"."\x05"."\x03"."\x06"."\x02"."\x01"."\x07"."\xff"."\xc4"."\x00"."\x32"."\x10"."\x00"."\x02"."\x01"."\x03"."\x02"."\x05"."\x03"."\x03"."\x02"."\x05"."\x05"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x01"."\x02"."\x03"."\x00"."\x04"."\x11"."\x12"."\x21"."\x05"."\x13"."\x31"."\x41"."\x51"."\x06"."\x22"."\x61"."\x14"."\x32"."\x71"."\x23"."\xa1"."\x15"."\x24"."\x33"."\x81"."\x91"."\x42"."\x52"."\xb1"."\xd1"."\xf0"."\xff"."\xc4"."\x00"."\x16"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x01"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x01"."\x02"."\xff"."\xc4"."\x00"."\x1b"."\x11"."\x01"."\x00"."\x02"."\x02"."\x03"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x00"."\x01"."\x11"."\x02"."\x21"."\x22"."\x41"."\x61"."\xff"."\xda"."\x00"."\x0c"."\x03"."\x01"."\x00"."\x02"."\x11"."\x03"."\x11"."\x00"."\x3f"."\x00"."\xfc"."\x99"."\x52"."\xb4"."\x58"."\x8f"."\x8a"."\x62"."\x18"."\x73"."\x4c"."\xad"."\xb6"."\x07"."\x4a"."\x8d"."\x12"."\x58"."\xbe"."\x2b"."\x41"."\x17"."\xc5"."\x3f"."\x1d"."\xa6"."\x7b"."\x53"."\x31"."\xd8"."\xe7"."\xb5"."\x41"."\x27"."\x94"."\x45"."\x02"."\x33"."\xe2"."\xac"."\x3d"."\x91"."\x03"."\xed"."\xaf"."\x22"."\xd3"."\x6e"."\x94"."\x12"."\xb9"."\x66"."\x81"."\x1b"."\x55"."\x61"."\x69"."\x9e"."\xd5"."\xaa"."\xd8"."\x64"."\x6c"."\x28"."\x22"."\x04"."\x65"."\x35"."\xba"."\x9c"."\xae"."\x08"."\xa7"."\xda"."\xcb"."\x0d"."\xb8"."\xaf"."\x46"."\xc8"."\x69"."\xce"."\x28"."\x25"."\x34"."\x6b"."\x9e"."\x95"."\x9b"."\xa0"."\x03"."\xa5"."\x51"."\x7b"."\x62"."\xb4"."\xac"."\xb1"."\x9a"."\x09"."\xaf"."\x08"."\x2d"."\x45"."\x32"."\x53"."\x7a"."\x2a"."\x87"."\xad"."\x63"."\x18"."\x06"."\x9f"."\x48"."\x81"."\xda"."\x96"."\xb4"."\x43"."\x81"."\xb5"."\x54"."\xb7"."\x8e"."\x36"."\x60"."\xaf"."\x28"."\x4a"."\x83"."\xec"."\x56"."\xe8"."\x00"."\xda"."\x9b"."\x86"."\x24"."\x1e"."\x2b"."\xea"."\xc5"."\x6e"."\xc4"."\xa2"."\xdc"."\x61"."\x94"."\x6e"."\x06"."\xe6"."\xb7"."\x16"."\xf1"."\xf2"."\xf0"."\x99"."\x77"."\xff"."\x00"."\x71"."\x34"."\x18"."\x4c"."\x21"."\xc8"."\x05"."\x94"."\x7c"."\x50"."\x56"."\x00"."\x00"."\x18"."\xc9"."\xe9"."\xb5"."\x69"."\x1d"."\x8a"."\x86"."\x01"."\x80"."\x24"."\xf9"."\xa7"."\xe3"."\xe1"."\xeb"."\x22"."\xea"."\x00"."\x64"."\x7d"."\xb4"."\x12"."\x79"."\x2a"."\x18"."\x8c"."\x74"."\xaf"."\x58"."\x55"."\xee"."\x05"."\x5d"."\xb8"."\xb0"."\x8b"."\x96"."\xb2"."\xe0"."\x2b"."\x67"."\x04"."\x52"."\x33"."\x59"."\x68"."\x70"."\x1d"."\x40"."\x53"."\xd0"."\xf6"."\x34"."\x42"."\x3c"."\x95"."\x90"."\x65"."\x70"."\x6b"."\x07"."\x81"."\x86"."\x70"."\x2a"."\xd2"."\xdb"."\x7d"."\x3a"."\xe5"."\x54"."\x15"."\xf0"."\x77"."\xc5"."\x27"."\x75"."\x71"."\x14"."\x71"."\xe5"."\xe2"."\x19"."\x53"."\xee"."\x20"."\xe3"."\x6a"."\x09"."\x32"."\x43"."\xb1"."\xc8"."\xa9"."\xf3"."\xc3"."\xb9"."\xda"."\xad"."\x49"."\x71"."\x66"."\xce"."\x15"."\x2e"."\x01"."\xc8"."\xc9"."\x38"."\xc8"."\x5f"."\x8a"."\x5e"."\xe6"."\x14"."\xea"."\xa4"."\x30"."\x23"."\xa8"."\xa2"."\xb9"."\xd9"."\x23"."\xc3"."\x9a"."\x29"."\xd9"."\x62"."\x1a"."\xce"."\xd4"."\x50"."\x37"."\x60"."\xa1"."\x90"."\x6d"."\x5d"."\x67"."\xa6"."\xbd"."\x1b"."\xfc"."\x62"."\x19"."\xee"."\xaf"."\x79"."\x90"."\xc4"."\xa0"."\x84"."\x23"."\x6c"."\x9f"."\x35"."\xc9"."\xd9"."\x48"."\x63"."\xc1"."\x53"."\x82"."\x3b"."\xd7"."\xe9"."\x31"."\x7a"."\xae"."\xdf"."\x83"."\x7a"."\x46"."\x18"."\xa4"."\x90"."\xcd"."\x7d"."\xc9"."\x27"."\x42"."\x8e"."\xfd"."\xb3"."\x55"."\x1c"."\x0d"."\x85"."\x91"."\xb4"."\xba"."\x9a"."\x26"."\x62"."\xec"."\xae"."\x43"."\x39"."\xee"."\x01"."\xda"."\xaf"."\x42"."\x11"."\x23"."\xdc"."\x81"."\xdc"."\xd4"."\x4e"."\x17"."\x33"."\x4e"."\x65"."\x96"."\x42"."\x79"."\x8e"."\xd9"."\x6c"."\xf9"."\xef"."\x55"."\xc0"."\x66"."\x6d"."\x5a"."\x3f"."\x4f"."\x60"."\x76"."\xa8"."\x1f"."\xb3"."\xb5"."\xfa"."\x89"."\xb5"."\x7f"."\xa7"."\xce"."\x29"."\xc9"."\x12"."\x2b"."\x54"."\xd5"."\xb7"."\x5d"."\xb3"."\x58"."\x70"."\xfe"."\x2b"."\x03"."\x40"."\xf0"."\x1c"."\x2b"."\x28"."\xc0"."\xdb"."\x6a"."\xde"."\xe2"."\x48"."\xe7"."\xb4"."\x07"."\x57"."\x51"."\xd3"."\xc1"."\xaa"."\x3e"."\xc6"."\xca"."\xe4"."\x03"."\xee"."\x04"."\xe4"."\x6d"."\x5a"."\xcb"."\x6a"."\x92"."\xa9"."\x52"."\x33"."\x9e"."\xfe"."\x2a"."\x77"."\x06"."\x98"."\x3a"."\x33"."\x48"."\xdb"."\x03"."\xa4"."\x03"."\xe4"."\x53"."\x8f"."\xc4"."\x63"."\xb7"."\xd6"."\xcc"."\x33"."\xe0"."\x03"."\x41"."\x2a"."\x79"."\x4d"."\xa4"."\xdc"."\x89"."\x03"."\x78"."\xd4"."\x46"."\xc4"."\x54"."\xcb"."\xe3"."\x80"."\x4a"."\xef"."\xa7"."\xf7"."\x14"."\xfb"."\xdc"."\x7f"."\x16"."\x66"."\xc6"."\x03"."\x29"."\xdc"."\x9f"."\x14"."\x85"."\xed"."\xb4"."\xb1"."\xc4"."\x70"."\x43"."\xe9"."\xc8"."\x24"."\x1e"."\xa2"."\xa0"."\xea"."\x7d"."\x01"."\xc2"."\x38"."\x74"."\x9c"."\x12"."\x60"."\xf6"."\xf1"."\xcb"."\xce"."\x73"."\xcc"."\x76"."\x19"."\x23"."\xe0"."\x54"."\x1f"."\x52"."\x70"."\x28"."\x78"."\x2f"."\x10"."\x6b"."\x68"."\xa7"."\xd6"."\x8d"."\xee"."\x45"."\x23"."\x75"."\x1e"."\x2a"."\x5f"."\x00"."\xf5"."\x1d"."\xff"."\x00"."\x04"."\x91"."\x5a"."\xda"."\x5d"."\x51"."\xcc"."\xe5"."\x4c"."\x2d"."\xd3"."\x23"."\xbd"."\x5a"."\xe2"."\xdc"."\x7e"."\x5e"."\x31"."\x22"."\xf3"."\x63"."\x48"."\xf2"."\xbe"."\xe5"."\xee"."\x08"."\xaa"."\x39"."\x39"."\x62"."\xfd"."\x43"."\xb5"."\x14"."\xc4"."\xe0"."\x73"."\x4e"."\xf4"."\x54"."\x54"."\xb8"."\xae"."\x74"."\x2d"."\x32"."\xfc"."\x5b"."\xea"."\x30"."\x64"."\x8c"."\xae"."\x18"."\x65"."\x94"."\xf5"."\xa9"."\x48"."\x72"."\x2b"."\x60"."\x3d"."\x80"."\x79"."\x34"."\x15"."\xb8"."\x75"."\xc2"."\x41"."\x6f"."\x70"."\xe5"."\xc0"."\x3c"."\xc1"."\xf9"."\x20"."\xd5"."\x8e"."\x0f"."\xc5"."\x23"."\xbc"."\x52"."\x5e"."\xd2"."\x6f"."\xa7"."\x0c"."\x63"."\xfa"."\x83"."\x22"."\x80"."\x18"."\x63"."\xa2"."\x9c"."\x12"."\x32"."\xca"."\x36"."\xdf"."\x71"."\x80"."\x6a"."\x2d"."\xa8"."\x36"."\xc3"."\x98"."\x98"."\x61"."\xb8"."\x60"."\x7b"."\xd5"."\xee"."\x13"."\x77"."\xf4"."\xf1"."\x38"."\x84"."\xbc"."\x62"."\x56"."\xe6"."\x06"."\x11"."\xa3"."\x80"."\xd8"."\xd9"."\x86"."\xa0"."\x70"."\xdf"."\x23"."\xc5"."\x67"."\x2b"."\xad"."\x2c"."\x57"."\x6f"."\xb6"."\xf6"."\xa2"."\xd7"."\x8a"."\x4b"."\x13"."\xcc"."\x02"."\x03"."\xac"."\x12"."\x73"."\x9c"."\xf6"."\xff"."\x00"."\x9a"."\xe8"."\x23"."\x84"."\x48"."\x8e"."\x50"."\xe0"."\x32"."\x74"."\x1d"."\xab"."\x9c"."\xb6"."\x49"."\x21"."\x94"."\xab"."\xbb"."\x3c"."\x6a"."\x36"."\x2e"."\xa3"."\x27"."\x7d"."\xc7"."\xef"."\x5d"."\x37"."\x0b"."\xb4"."\x91"."\x52"."\x46"."\x32"."\x36"."\xe0"."\x85"."\xc0"."\xe9"."\xfd"."\xab"."\x4c"."\xc9"."\x4e"."\x11"."\x67"."\x24"."\x70"."\xca"."\x59"."\x40"."\xfd"."\x46"."\x3b"."\xef"."\xb5"."\x67"."\xc5"."\x52"."\x11"."\x01"."\x4c"."\x90"."\x47"."\xb8"."\x10"."\x3f"."\x6a"."\xbd"."\x69"."\x08"."\x50"."\xc8"."\x3a"."\x1c"."\xf5"."\x15"."\xcd"."\x71"."\x4b"."\x47"."\x49"."\x9c"."\x8c"."\x95"."\x27"."\x19"."\x3b"."\x11"."\xff"."\x00"."\xba"."\x55"."\x0b"."\x70"."\xb5"."\x10"."\x70"."\xa6"."\x6b"."\x58"."\xd6"."\x4b"."\xa9"."\x9b"."\x62"."\xf1"."\x3c"."\xa1"."\x72"."\x70"."\xa3"."\x0b"."\xb9"."\x27"."\x1b"."\x74"."\x1b"."\x1f"."\x15"."\x25"."\x2e"."\xb8"."\x8a"."\x71"."\x29"."\xc5"."\xdc"."\x11"."\xb7"."\x26"."\x67"."\x89"."\x9e"."\x26"."\x01"."\x1f"."\x49"."\x20"."\x95"."\xcf"."\x6d"."\xa9"."\xee"."\x1f"."\x6e"."\xf6"."\x06"."\x69"."\xd0"."\x30"."\x91"."\xc6"."\x96"."\x63"."\x2b"."\x0f"."\x6f"."\x61"."\xb7"."\x6a"."\x97"."\x73"."\x2c"."\x92"."\xdc"."\x88"."\x36"."\x1a"."\xbb"."\x28"."\xc0"."\x55"."\xc5"."\x63"."\x95"."\xf8"."\xd6"."\xa9"."\x2e"."\x55"."\xb8"."\x9f"."\x0b"."\x03"."\x04"."\x1a"."\x89"."\x04"."\xf5"."\xc9"."\xaa"."\x3c"."\x3b"."\x87"."\xdc"."\x59"."\xa3"."\xbc"."\xf3"."\x19"."\x1d"."\x86"."\xdb"."\xd2"."\xef"."\xa6"."\x32"."\x42"."\x0d"."\xc6"."\x0e"."\x6a"."\x9c"."\x33"."\x73"."\x2d"."\x94"."\xd6"."\x90"."\xa4"."\x80"."\xeb"."\x39"."\xa2"."\x89"."\x7f"."\xa8"."\x77"."\xa2"."\x82"."\x0c"."\x7d"."\x05"."\x30"."\xab"."\xa8"."\x60"."\xf6"."\xa5"."\x62"."\x38"."\x02"."\x9f"."\xb7"."\x50"."\xd4"."\x14"."\x2c"."\x31"."\x24"."\x2c"."\xa7"."\xc5"."\x6b"."\xc3"."\x6f"."\xcd"."\xbc"."\xc2"."\xda"."\x41"."\x90"."\x0e"."\x14"."\x9d"."\xa9"."\x28"."\xa5"."\x6b"."\x59"."\xb5"."\x03"."\xed"."\x6d"."\x8d"."\x69"."\x17"."\x29"."\xee"."\x23"."\x92"."\x59"."\x31"."\x18"."\x6d"."\x6c"."\x31"."\xbf"."\xe2"."\x83"."\xa8"."\x45"."\x59"."\x6e"."\x81"."\x61"."\xfa"."\x43"."\x07"."\xf3"."\x5d"."\x6d"."\xb4"."\x44"."\x28"."\x7c"."\xe0"."\x30"."\xce"."\x3c"."\x57"."\x13"."\x6d"."\x76"."\xb3"."\x13"."\xc9"."\x38"."\x04"."\x6f"."\xf1"."\x5d"."\x6d"."\xad"."\xd1"."\x36"."\xe9"."\xcc"."\x3a"."\x17"."\x48"."\x38"."\xfe"."\xd5"."\x50"."\xda"."\xa1"."\x8a"."\x63"."\xa4"."\x8d"."\x27"."\xcd"."\x25"."\xc4"."\x61"."\x53"."\x0b"."\xc8"."\xf9"."\x31"."\xe3"."\xdd"."\xf1"."\xf3"."\x5b"."\x7d"."\x44"."\x52"."\x00"."\xca"."\xc0"."\xaf"."\x6a"."\x9f"."\xc6"."\x5a"."\x46"."\xb1"."\x60"."\x84"."\xb2"."\x67"."\x3e"."\xd3"."\xb8"."\xff"."\x00"."\xba"."\x0e"."\x67"."\x88"."\xdd"."\xbd"."\xac"."\x72"."\x68"."\x21"."\x80"."\x18"."\x0c"."\x3b"."\xd4"."\x1e"."\x1f"."\x39"."\x6b"."\x89"."\x6e"."\x25"."\x1b"."\x9e"."\xd9"."\xe9"."\x4c"."\xdf"."\x5f"."\xe9"."\x2c"."\xac"."\xa0"."\xa3"."\x0c"."\x30"."\xa9"."\x6f"."\x22"."\x2a"."\x04"."\x8c"."\x1d"."\xc7"."\xf9"."\xa8"."\xad"."\x64"."\x99"."\x5d"."\xdc"."\xaf"."\x42"."\x69"."\xfb"."\x12"."\xcd"."\x6e"."\x71"."\xda"."\xa3"."\x96"."\x0b"."\x20"."\x41"."\xbe"."\x2a"."\xf7"."\x0a"."\x4f"."\xe5"."\x0b"."\x1e"."\xf4"."\x0b"."\xc8"."\x1f"."\x59"."\xa2"."\xb6"."\x94"."\x8e"."\x61"."\xa2"."\x83"."\x96"."\x59"."\x30"."\x29"."\xfb"."\x59"."\x77"."\xc8"."\x35"."\x23"."\x56"."\xd5"."\xb4"."\x37"."\x05"."\x0f"."\x5a"."\xa2"."\xdb"."\x48"."\x85"."\x7d"."\xdb"."\x83"."\xd6"."\x96"."\x12"."\x00"."\xcc"."\xb9"."\xf6"."\x9e"."\x84"."\xd2"."\xad"."\x70"."\x59"."\x76"."\xaf"."\x0b"."\x23"."\x38"."\x0a"."\x3a"."\x93"."\x81"."\x50"."\x75"."\xbe"."\x9b"."\x54"."\x99"."\x4b"."\x4a"."\xe5"."\x40"."\xdb"."\x6a"."\xa3"."\x79"."\xc6"."\xe2"."\x81"."\x7e"."\x9e"."\x47"."\xcb"."\xae"."\x46"."\x33"."\xfe"."\x0d"."\x73"."\xf6"."\x17"."\x1f"."\x4b"."\x69"."\x2a"."\x82"."\x0e"."\xb5"."\xd8"."\x8a"."\xce"."\xce"."\x7b"."\x68"."\x11"."\x64"."\x99"."\xc0"."\xd6"."\x72"."\xcc"."\xc7"."\x72"."\x68"."\x2b"."\xaf"."\xa9"."\x0a"."\x46"."\x21"."\xe6"."\xee"."\x1b"."\x23"."\x7d"."\xa9"."\xa5"."\xf5"."\x0a"."\xdc"."\x94"."\xb7"."\x56"."\x0a"."\xe4"."\x8e"."\x87"."\x1a"."\x87"."\x8a"."\x48"."\xde"."\xf0"."\xbd"."\x43"."\x54"."\x51"."\x95"."\xc7"."\xdd"."\x8d"."\xea"."\x2d"."\xf5"."\xe5"."\xad"."\xca"."\x39"."\x85"."\xbe"."\xd3"."\xed"."\x3d"."\xc1"."\xfc"."\xd1"."\x0e"."\x7a"."\x92"."\x18"."\xa2"."\xba"."\x59"."\x60"."\xfe"."\x94"."\x9e"."\xe0"."\x0f"."\x6f"."\x35"."\x10"."\xcf"."\xca"."\x5d"."\x64"."\x0c"."\xb1"."\x38"."\xf8"."\xa7"."\xf8"."\x84"."\xe6"."\xe6"."\x18"."\xc3"."\xb6"."\x0a"."\xa6"."\x90"."\x3e"."\x6a"."\x2c"."\x92"."\x6e"."\xb9"."\xc5"."\x14"."\xcc"."\x2f"."\xee"."\xd6"."\xd5"."\x6e"."\xde"."\xe8"."\xa5"."\xb0"."\x50"."\x76"."\xae"."\x65"."\xa6"."\x25"."\xb0"."\x3a"."\x53"."\xb1"."\x5e"."\xe5"."\x42"."\x0a"."\xa2"."\x94"."\x97"."\x24"."\xb9"."\xa2"."\xa6"."\xb4"."\xa4"."\xb7"."\x5a"."\x2a"."\x09"."\x79"."\xcd"."\x04"."\xed"."\x45"."\x15"."\x47"."\x9d"."\x6c"."\x0e"."\xc4"."\xd6"."\xf6"."\x8e"."\x59"."\xb7"."\x3d"."\x0d"."\x14"."\x51"."\x15"."\xe3"."\x76"."\x2b"."\x82"."\x7e"."\xe1"."\x93"."\xf9"."\xa2"."\x3b"."\x68"."\xae"."\x91"."\xd6"."\x55"."\x24"."\x0d"."\xf6"."\x26"."\x8a"."\x2a"."\x29"."\x19"."\x06"."\x89"."\xb9"."\x0a"."\x4e"."\x8c"."\x63"."\x14"."\xcc"."\xf0"."\xc3"."\x04"."\x76"."\xeb"."\x14"."\x4a"."\xba"."\xc1"."\x62"."\xdb"."\xe4"."\xd1"."\x45"."\x06"."\x72"."\xb1"."\x27"."\xf1"."\x81"."\x53"."\x64"."\x24"."\xc8"."\x49"."\xa2"."\x8a"."\xa3"."\xce"."\x4d"."\x6d"."\x6e"."\x7d"."\xd4"."\x51"."\x40"."\xd0"."\x19"."\xa2"."\x8a"."\x2a"."\x0f"."\xff"."\xd9";
echo $image;
```

This works too. I store images as a base64 string.  It is fool proof.  Very simple.  Stored in an SQL TEXT column.

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpg');
$filename = "pitbull3p.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");

$image = base64_encode(fread($handle, filesize($filename)));
$len = strlen($image);

echo base64_decode($image);
```

And gzcompress will get the base64 string down to about the size of the original binary image.  In this case less:

```
$image = gzcompress(base64_encode(fread($handle, filesize($filename))));
```

**1,864 bytes original jpg image

2,488  bytes base64 before compression.

1,833  bytes after compression.**

Also I noticed I did not put the `header()` in my previous code.  It's there now.

**end of update 2**

---

### Update

I assumed the problem was in saving the image into the BLOB.  I used PHPmyAdmin to save the image. When I wrote some code to save the image I had problems.

This is the code I finally got to work.  Starting with an empty table.

I used `fread` because it is binary safe.  converted the files data to HEX and appended the hex to'0x'.

It was important the `$image`  did not have single quotes in the query string.

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpg');
$filename = "pitbull3p.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$image = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$image = '0x' . bin2hex($image);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `isl_contact`.`image` (`id`, `image`) VALUES (1,$image)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_errno() > 0){echo mysql_error() . "\n$sql";}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM `image` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); 
echo $row[0];
```

**end of update**

---

I just did the same and it worked fine.

How did you get the image into the table?

When I viewed the script in the Browser the image came up as it should.

[image: dog]

Saved a jpg image in a LONGBLOB

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpg');    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM `image` WHERE `id` = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); 
echo $row[0];
```

This is my test database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `image` (`id`, `image`) VALUES
(1, 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);

  // Notice there are no quote marks around the Hex
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to test this code, but I will do it as soon as possible.  This was an awesome answer so I'm hoping it helps.

Comment: Update: I tried this and it wouldn't work, even with your code as a sudo test.  I've also tried moving stuff and changing how everything is positioned.   

https://gist.github.com/ddavisgraphics/5425af10e930d29a731c

Comment: See Update 2.  What you have is a "Hexadecimal representation of data", that will not help.

Comment: I'm still not getting the result I'm looking for, I've used the setup in the second setup, but I think that something is messing up in the storage of the file because I get an error that says image can't be displayed because it shows errors.

Comment: I went back and checked my original code and your first update works, there was a single space typo that was printing data before the header was given.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe upload the image to server folder and save only the path to the image. It's more efficient.