# image saved as blob does not display

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]I have followed these examples

- [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)
- [How to display an BLOB image stored in MySql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214602/how-to-display-an-blob-image-stored-in-mysql-database)

Have same way of displaying image saved as blob. I have field name picture longblob

```js
if ( ! $(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost') ) {
    var element = $("<input type='file' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
    element.attr("name",$(this).attr("name"));
    element.change(function(){
     element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
    });
```

to save in table  i put it in an array and save in table along other fields 
[image]

saved in db like this now i want to display image in table row it in table row 
by using this

```html
<td> echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' .base64_encode( $row['Picture_File'] ). '" />';?></td>
```

It gives error of

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

I want to display image as well as allow to download it

---

After implementing @Hassaan's answer I got the following output.

[image]

Comment: Somewhere you are using something as an array which is actually an object. Could be that $row["Picture_File"] should be $row->Picture_File. But I cannot see the code that generates your $row variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be you are using OOP method of Database connection. I hope the following will resolve the issue.

Replace

```
$row['Picture_File']
```

into

```
$row->Picture_File
```

Full line of code

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row->Picture_File).'">';
```

**NOTE**:

Make sure to change mime type near `image/png;` to respective.
For example if jpg then change into `image/jpeg;` etc

---

**Tip**

While save image as blob into database, you may need to store mime type too.

Comment: echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' .base64_encode( $row->Picture_File ). '" />';

Comment: @Sarah_Salar Make sure you are aso assigning right mime type to image. I have updated my answer as well with example.

Comment: @Sarah_Salar as you are saving other data into database. Just get mime type of image and save into separate field.

Comment: if select mime type in creating a field in the table does it work

Comment: @Sarah_Salar I did not get it. For this issue you can ask new question. As of issue mentioned in this question is resolved. You can mark tick on my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: kindly view new pic added

Comment: @Sarah_Salar ok yes this will work. You just need to pass selected type to post request and save into database field. You can also auto detect this via PHP easily

Comment: u meant i have to create another filed for this? but how does it work with image field

Comment: While fetching blob data from database, you also need to fetch the field where mime is stored and use this in code near `image/png` as `'.$row->mime_type_field.'`

Comment: <img src="data:image/png;base64," .base64_encode(a.png).="" '=""> but image row show this path and it contains image type so why i need to save type in another field